# send parameter from js file to jsp file with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

Here is my js file where my goal is to send variable va to jsp file and output it. The problem I can't find the bug.

```
 $(function(){
    $("td").click(function(){

        var date = $(this).html();
        var message = prompt(year+"year "+month+"month "+ date+"day","null!");
        this.append(message);   
        var variable = "mememem";
        var sendData = new XMLHttpRequest();
        sendData.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              alert("connected to server");
            }
          };

        sendData.open('GET','dataFile.jsp?na='+variable,true);
        sendData.send(null);
        window.location = "dataFile.jsp"; 

    })
});
```

///////////////////////////javascript file//////////////////////

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-KR"
    pageEncoding="EUC-KR"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=EUC-KR">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
String name = request.getParameter("na");

out.print(name);
%>
</body>
</html>
```

///////////////////jsp file

Comment: What "bug"? What goes wrong? What are the errors?

Comment: @Pointy request.getParameter("na"); sends out null

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you're sending **variable** instead of **va**.

This line:

```
sendData.open('GET','dataFile.jsp?na='+variable,true);
```

Hope that is the root cause of your problem.

Comment: @Denico no va isn't the problem